# How to obtain a single value from site's api?

Tags: javascript, json, api, http, get

There's this site:

https://turtle-coin.com/#api

When you go into hashrate, a single value is displayed. I need to capture that value, but don't really know how.

So far I've tried this:

```
function getNetworkData(){
$.getJSON('../json/networks/network-list.json', function(data) {

    data.networks.forEach(function(network){

    var api_url = network.hashrate_url;

        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", api_url);
        try {
            xmlHttp.send();
            responseText = xmlHttp.responseText;
            var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.error(ex);
        }

    console.log(data);

        });

});
}
```

I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

This is the code to print the hashrate:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:11898/getinfo');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result, TRUE);
curl_close($ch);
//print_r($obj);
$difficulty = $obj['difficulty'];
$hashrate = round($difficulty / 30);
print_r($hashrate);
?>
```

---

**EDIT2**

Well, at first I was getting:

```
Failed to load https://turtle-coin.com/q/hashrate/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But I dealt with it installing chrome plugin called CORS.

Now the script is working fine, but it logs no values. I see a function call in console, but it's just empty. No value captured.

Comment: Can you print out the api_url. It could very well be that the response isn't a json document

Comment: This is the url: `https://turtle-coin.com/q/hashrate`. I found a php code to print that and i'll past that in an edit.

Comment: Yeah, that's not JSON, no need to parse the response from `https://turtle-coin.com/q/hashrate`

Comment: That just a simple change? `var data = responseText;`?

Comment: yes, that would be sufficient

Comment: Can you please take a look at my edit? There seems to be a problem as there's no value captured.